# How can I replace a type in a template at any level of nesting?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-meta-programming

I have a type named `the_bad`. I want to replace that type with `the_good` using a template metafunction. I expect that template metafunction to be quite complex so let's call it `the_ugly`.

My problem is that `the_bad` could be nested in other templates, and I want to leave the other templates and parameters untouched. Here's an example of what I mean, with an incomplete implementation of `the_ugly`:

```cpp
struct the_good {};
struct the_bad {};

template<typename T>
struct the_ugly_impl {
    using type = T;
};

template<>
struct the_ugly_impl<the_bad> {
    using type = the_good;
};

template<typename T>
using the_ugly = typename the_ugly_impl<T>::type;

// passes, yay!
static_assert(std::same_as<the_good, the_ugly<the_bad>>);

// doesn't pass
static_assert(std::same_as<std::vector<the_good>, the_ugly<std::vector<the_bad>>>);

// doesn't pass
static_assert(std::same_as<std::list<std::vector<the_good>>, the_ugly<std::list<std::vector<the_bad>>>>);
```

How can I fix `the_ugly` so that it replaces `the_bad` to `the_good` at any nesting level, while keeping all other template and other template parameters untouched?

Comment: You need extra specialization to handle nested types.

Comment: Honestly? I'd do it like this (1) wait for the reflection working group to pasd something. (2) write a generic utility utilising proper reflection. (3) ???? (4) profit.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Even if reflection comes out, my code is strictly C++20 and will likely stay like that for a while. I'm asking here since I need help with this problem with current tech, not in 10 to 20 years from now. At this point, I don't expect reflection to ever come out, and even if it does, it very likely that I won't even work in my project at that point.

Comment: Actually in case of nested types this isn't too complicated. The showstopper would be non-type template parameters. Like std::array. I don't think we're quite there, yet...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yeah, I think if you want a 100% general case you would have to wait for reflection to come out like story teller said.

Comment: Sorry if my tounge-in-cheek was a bit offputting. Maybe something like https://wg21.link/P1985 is more likely to happen, and make this possible.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica thanks for the link. Yes that feature would be incredibly helpful!

Comment: Reflection is neither here nor there. Reflection gives you introspection of objects. Here, what's needed is the means of specializing a template for either a type or a non-type template parameter. Reflection is not a factor.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the TS for reflection in C++ is much broader than just runtime introspection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to handle the template case, and have that invoke itself recursively:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct the_ugly_impl {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
using the_ugly = typename the_ugly_impl<T>::type;

template<>
struct the_ugly_impl<the_bad> {
    using type = the_good;
};

template <template <typename...> class L, typename... Ts>
struct the_ugly_impl<L<Ts...>> {
    using type = L<the_ugly<Ts>...>;
};
```

Comment: Non-type template parameter has joined the chat :(  Upped anyway

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yeah I kinda get what you meant then. I guess that will do though. I can handle a few common case and call it a day